# Connecting to MS SQL Server 2005 from Mac using Ruby, ODBC and FreeTDS

Tags: sql-server, ruby, database, odbc, unixodbc

I'm having trouble connecting to a SQL Server 2005 install from this very simple Ruby app:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'sequel'

Sequel.odbc('dev04')['select top 1 * from users'].all
```

The `dev04` DSN points to my `odbc.ini` file entry:

```
[dev04]
Driver      = FreeTDS
Description = ODBC connection via FreeTDS
Trace       = 1
Servername  = dev04
Database    = Dev04
UID         = uDev04
PWD         = pwdDev04
```

`FreeTDS` is installed in odbcinst.ini and it points to this configuration in `freetds.conf`:

```
[dev04]
host = hm602.mycompany.com
port = 1433
tds version = 7.0
```

This works:

```
carlos$ tsql -S dev04 -U uDev04 -P pwdDev04
locale is "en_GB.UTF-8"
locale charset is "UTF-8"
1> exit
carlos$
```

And so does this:

```
carlos$ iodbctest "DSN=dev04;UID=uDev04;PWD=pwdDev04"
iODBC Demonstration program
This program shows an interactive SQL processor
Driver Manager: 03.52.0406.1211
Driver: 0.82 (libtdsodbc.so)

SQL>exit 

Have a nice day.
carlos$
```

When I run that Ruby script, though, I get this error:

```
carlos$ ruby mssql.rb 
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sequel-3.4.0/lib/sequel/adapters/odbc.rb:37:in `initialize': ODBC::Error 01000 (20002) [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Adaptive Server connection failed (Sequel::DatabaseConnectionError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sequel-3.4.0/lib/sequel/adapters/odbc.rb:37:in `connect'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sequel-3.4.0/lib/sequel/adapters/odbc.rb:37:in `connect'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sequel-3.4.0/lib/sequel/database.rb:92:in `initialize'
...
```

I understand the 'Adaptive Server connection failed' error can occur due to TDS protocol version discrepancies. I've checked the logs and they all seem to be using the correct version (7.0), so I'm at a complete loss as to why this could be happening.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the Sequel maintainer.  Unfortunately, I don't have any personal experience using Sequel to connect to MSSQL using FreeTDS.  I know other people have used it successfully though.

Your error message indicates a issue in the underlying Ruby/ODBC library, not in Sequel itself.  If you can get a connection working using Ruby/ODBC directly, it shouldn't be hard to get it working with Sequel.

Sorry I can't be more help.

Also, while it is unrelated to your current issue, you should use the :db_type=>'mssql' option to the Sequel.odbc call.

Comment: Hi Jeremy! Thanks for taking your time to answer this.

I've tried connecting with the latest ActiveRecord, and apparently this works:

  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection({
    :adapter => 'sqlserver',
    :mode => 'odbc',
    :dsn => 'Dev04',
    :username => 'uDev04',
    :password => 'pwdDev04'
  })

I'm using activerecord 2.3.4 with rails-sqlserver-2000-2005-adapter 2.2.19, AFAICT. Unfortunately, AR won't help me much (this is a badly evolved legacy schema), and Sequel would do the job perfectly.

I'm keen to help fixing this, but don't know where to start. Ideas?

Comment: You could try:

  Sequel.odbc('Dev04', :user=>'uDev04', :password=>'pwdDev04')

I'm not sure that will work, but it's worth a shot.  If that doesn't work, I can take a look at the AR SQLServer adapter code to see how it's using Ruby/ODBC differently.  Just to be sure, are you using activerecord-sqlserver-adapter version 2.2.21?

Comment: I'm using activerecord-sqlserver-adapter 2.2.19 and rails-sqlserver-2000-2005-adapter 2.2.19 (as far as I know, they're the latest versions as of writing this), with Rails 2.3.4.

Comment: I looked at the activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-2.2.21 code (which is the latest version).  It actually uses DBI to connect (via DBI::ODBC), not ODBC directly.  You could try using Sequel with:

  DB = Sequel.dbi('DBI:ODBC:Dev04', :user => 'uDev04', :password => 'pwdDev04')

Sequel's DBI adapter doesn't support the shared SQL Subadapter yet, but if you can get it to connect, I'll add support for it.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, free isn't without cost.

TDS Version 7.0 was correct for SQL Server 7.x, and it will connect in many cases to later versions of SQL Server -- but it does not support all features or functionality of those later versions.

TDS Version 7.1 is correct for SQL Server 2000 (v8.x); 7.2 is correct for SQL Server 2005 (v9.x); 7.3 is correct for SQL Server 2008 (v10.x).  Due to some confusion in Microsoft's documentation, these are usually specified in the freetds.conf using the SQL Server version, not the TDS version; and SQL Server 2008 isn't fully supported yet; so I'd test with

```
tds version = 7.1
tds version = 7.2
tds version = 8.0
tds version = 9.0
```

Or ... you could try using a [commercial driver like this one from my employer](http://download.openlinksw.com/downwiz/product_matrix.vsp?p=l_db&c=28&of=5) that has already handled much of the head-scratching.  If you do go that route, I'd suggest you also review the [full documentation for the Rails ODBC Adapter](http://odbc-rails.rubyforge.org/)

ObDisclaimer: I work for OpenLink Software, but do not directly benefit from anyone choosing to use our products.

Comment: You should disclose your affiliation when recommending commercial products produced by your employer.